# Regular Expression - Matching and extracting complicated conditions

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression that will match these conditions:

- Maximum of 8000 characters (any characters, including "\r\n")
- Maximum of 10 lines (separated by \r\n).
- to extract from the matched text **only the first 4 lines**.

Can't find a good way do it...:/

Thanks!!

Comment: There are ways to do it with regex, but none of them are **good** ways

Comment: Which language/tool are you using? Also, you wish to extract the first 4 lines - what happens if there are less than 4 lines?

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are not what you need. They are used to match a certain **pattern**, not a certain length. If you are holding the data in a `string`, `myString.length <= 8000` is all you need for the character count (using the correct syntax for your language, of course). For the number of lines, you will have to count the number of `\r\n` sequences in your string (can be done iteratively). To get the first four lines, just find the 4th `\r\n` and get everything before that with a `substring` method.

Comment: -1 for wrong information. Using a repetition expression in regex like `.{0,8000}` would allow you to match between zero and 8000 characters. If you wanted to match an exact quantity of characters then you could use `.{8000}`. But don't take my word for it you can read more about over here  http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html.

Answer (score 1):

## Description

This expression does the following:

- validates the input string is between zero and 8,000 characters
- validates there are at most 10 line of new line delimited text
- then captures the first 4 new line delimited lines of text

`\A(?=.{0,8000}\Z)(?=(?:^.*?(?:\r|\n|\Z)){0,10}\Z)(?:^.*?[\r\n\Z]+){0,4}` This requires options: `m` multiline, and `s` dot matches all characters

[image]

## Expanded

- `\A` anchor to the begining of the string, this anchor allows the use of the `s` option which allows the `.` to match new line and line feed characters
- `(?=.{0,8000}\Z)` look ahead and validate there are between zero and 8000 characters
- `(?=(?:^.*?(?:\r|\n|\Z)){0,10}\Z)` look ahead and validate there are no more then 10 new line delimited lines
- `(?:^.*?[\r\n\Z]+){0,4}` match the first 4 lines of text

## PHP Code Example:

You didn't specify a language so I'm including this PHP example to show how it works and the sample output.

**Input Text**

This input test is 8 lines of new line delimited strings. There are only 1779 characters here.

```
Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small 
river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth. Even the all-powerful Pointing has no control about 
the blind texts it is an almost unorthographic life One day however a small line of blind text by the name of Lorem Ipsum decided to leave for the far World of Grammar. The Big Oxmox advised her not to do so, because there were 
thousands of bad Commas, wild Question Marks and devious Semikoli, but the Little Blind Text didn’t listen. She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way. When she reached the first hills of 
the Italic Mountains, she had a last view back on the skyline of her hometown Bookmarksgrove, the headline of Alphabet Village and the subline of her own road, the Line Lane. Pityful a rethoric question ran over her cheek, then 
she continued her way. On her way she met a copy. The copy warned the Little Blind Text, that where it came from it would have been rewritten a thousand times and everything that was left from its origin would be the word "and" 
and the Little Blind Text should turn around and return to its own, safe country. But nothing the copy said could convince her and so it didn’t take long until a few insidious Copy Writers ambushed her, made her drunk with Longe 
and Parole and dragged her into their agency, where they abused her for their projects again and again. And if she hasn’t been rewritten, then they are still using her.
```

**Code**

```
<?php
$sourcestring="your source string";
preg_match('/\A(?=.{0,8000}\Z)(?=(?:^.*?(?:\r|\n|\Z)){0,10}\Z)(?:^.*?[\r|\n\Z]+){0,4}/ims',$sourcestring,$matches);
echo "<pre>".print_r($matches,true);
?>
```

**Matches**

```
$matches Array:
(
    [0] => Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small 
river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth. Even the all-powerful Pointing has no control about 
the blind texts it is an almost unorthographic life One day however a small line of blind text by the name of Lorem Ipsum decided to leave for the far World of Grammar. The Big Oxmox advised her not to do so, because there were 
thousands of bad Commas, wild Question Marks and devious Semikoli, but the Little Blind Text didn’t listen. She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way. When she reached the first hills of 

)
```